# Access AWS Fargate service from AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I have a few services in an **AWS ECS** cluster, using **Fargate** launch type. Those services are all in the **same VPC** and discover each other using **Service Connect**. The whole thing is behind an Application Load Balancer (ALB) which handles HTTP(S) traffic.

Now I'd like to access one of those services (a database) from an **AWS Batch Job**. The batch job is currently launched into the **same VPC** as well. Unfortunately (but not suprisingly) the batch job can't find the database service, because batch jobs seem to not use Service Connect.

How can I make this database service discoverable and accessible for the AWS Batch Job?

Comment: As far as I can tell, ECS Service Connect uses AWS Cloud Map. Cloud Map is mentioned several times in the ECS Service Connect documentation. You could verify that by going into the AWS Cloud Map console in your AWS account and seeing if your services are listed in there. You would have to use the AWS SDK or AWS CLI tool inside the batch job to query AWS Cloud Map to get the address of your services in there.

Comment: +1 you would need to query CloudMap in the container image of the Batch job to get the endpoint to connect to.